# Tableau Filter another attribute data based on the excluded value from another attribute

Tags: tableau-api

We are trying to build a small inventory project I need to exclude the product, and along with it need to exclude the ingredients that are being used to make that product.

If I exclude the product Bowl, need to remove all its ingredients from the other products. e.g. chicken should disappear from Burrito and Bell Pepper should be excluded from Sandwich aggregation.

Following is my sample data

```
Product,    Ingredient Type,    Ingredient 
Bowl,            Meat,           Chicken 
Burrito,         Meat,           Beef 
Burrito,         Meat,           Chicken 
Bowl,            Vegies,         Bell Pepper 
Bowl,            Vegies,         Lettuce 
Burrito,         Vegies,         Lettuce 
Bowl,            Vegies,         Onions 
Burrito,         Beans,          Black 
Bowl             Beans           Brown 
Sandwich         Vegies          Bell Pepper
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach:

Assuming you exclude the required product using parameter, First you need to select the values that are excluded that can be done by using the LoD `Fixed`.

Create a calculation field `Calcualtion 2`

```
{ FIXED [Ingredient]:
 MIN(IF [Product] = [Parameters].[Product] THEN [Ingredient] END)}
```

Now use this formula to compare the values and exclude those for other products:

```
IF [Ingredient] = [Calculation2]
THEN NULL
ELSE [Ingredient]
END
```

Use above formula in place of Ingradient column